# Selectively sync contacts from Windows Live

Tags: 8.0, windows-live

I have a lot of contacts in Windows Live after starting to use Windows Phone since version 7. My problem is, that a lot of those contacts don't really need to be on my phone, I just need them to be in the web interface.

Is it possible to limit the contacts synchronised to a number of groups or exclude contacts that are in a certain group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not sync contacts selectively. Either you sync all contacts or none. So I see two options:

- Create a second live account and move the contacts there
- Create a group where all contacts are in want to have on the phone. That group will get synced to the phone and you can just look at this group

Both options are not very convenient but currently the only way to go.